# Can you pass a variable to a VALUE in SQL?

Tags: sql

I was just wondering whether it is possible to pass a variable to the VALUE parameter of a query.  Basically my form has a list box of which a user inputs names of the cast members which belong to a certain film, the list is then stored in the db so that it can be redisplayed when the record is pulled back up - here is my existing code.

```
Private Sub btnAddSubject_Click()

Dim s As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb


s = lstItems.RowSource & txtItems & ";"

lstItems.RowSource = s

db.Execute "INSERT INTO Cast_and_Crew (Name) VALUES ('@s')"
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

you can create string by concatenation:

```
db.Execute "INSERT INTO Cast_and_Crew (Name) VALUES ('" & s & "')"
```

Comment: I would say it's generally not a good idea, it would easily introduce sql injection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) problem.